# Execute part of code if there was and exception or not

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

In programming language like `C#` we do have something like `finally` block which purpose is if code encounter an error so that `catch` section will be called.

Nevertheless if there was or wasn't an error there is `finally` block which will be called. My question is do we have something  similar to finally block in PL/pgSQL as I wasn't able to find so far?

```
  try {
       //particular code
    }
    catch{
       //execute when there was an error
    }
    finally{
       // execute whenever was or not an error
    }
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)  there is nothing equivalent to `finally` in PL/pgSQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so by means no possibility/pattern or whatever way to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: Just put code right after the `try`/`catch`. The only difference to `finally` is that it won't run if a) the try-block does an early `return` or b) the `catch` block does an early `return` or c) the `catch` block does re-throw an exception. But if you don't do that, you can achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Not in PL/pgSQL, no